# SAPUI5 - Hiding a table column?

Tags: sapui5

I have a a table rendered from an xml view.

Is there a way I can hide an entire column in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was this:

```
view.byId("DefaultTimesTable").getColumns()[4].setVisible(false)
```

Answer (score 4):

For the record, there are two Table controls in SAPUI5: `sap.m.Table` and `sap.ui.table.Table`

For both you can set the `visible` property of a Column to `false` to hide that Column.

```js
oTable.getColumns()[i].setVisible(false)
```

Edit:
Additional requirement from the comment:

To get the table in the Controller, use the Controller's `byId` function with the id of the Table:

```js
this.byId("tableId").getColumns()[i].setVisible(false)
```

(Given that `this` is the Controller instance.)

Comment: Thank you. Almost there....As the table was not create programmatically in the controller (it's just in the xml view), How do I actually access the table in the controller ?

Comment: That is a different problem with was not part of the original question, but see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Just stumbled over this Q in search for something else.
The more elegant way to solve your problem would be to create a model and a property for each column.

```
var oVisModel = new JSONModel({
            row1: "true",
            row2: "true"
});
this.setModel(oVisModel, "visModel");
```

Since JSONModels bind 2 way you now can bind the visible property in your XML

```
<m:Column
        id="row1"
        visible="{visModel>/row1}"
        minScreenWidth=""
        demandPopin="false">
        <m:Text text="{i18n>row1}" />
</m:Column>
```

If you now want to change the visibility in your controller you can smth like this:

```
//if model is bound to component.js
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("visModel").setProperty("/row1", "false");

//if model is bound to App.controller.js or how ever your main view controller is named
this.getView().getModel("visModel").setProperty("/row1", "false");
```

Even though the answer is kind of late, i hope it helps ppl who find this at a later point.

Regards,
Eric