# How to hide a column on the sap.m.Table?

Tags: sapui5

I am using the responsive table as following:

```
<m:Table id="csTable" inset="false" items="{ path: 'Orders>/', sorter: { path: 'OrderID' } }" enableBusyIndicator="true">
    <m:columns>
        <m:Column width="8em">
            <m:Text text="Order ID"/>
        </m:Column>
        <m:Column minScreenWidth="Medium" demandPopin="true">
            <m:Text text="Order date"/>
        </m:Column>
        <m:Column minScreenWidth="Desktop" demandPopin="true" hAlign="End">
            <m:Text text="Required date"/>
        </m:Column>
        <m:Column minScreenWidth="Desktop" demandPopin="true" hAlign="Center">
            <m:Text text="Postal code"/>
        </m:Column>
        <m:Column minScreenWidth="Desktop" demandPopin="true" hAlign="Center">
            <m:Text text="Ship city"/>
        </m:Column>
        <m:Column minScreenWidth="Desktop" demandPopin="true" hAlign="Center">
            <m:Text text="Ship country"/>
        </m:Column>
    </m:columns>
    <m:items>
        <m:ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="onPress">
            <m:cells>
                <m:ObjectIdentifier title="{Orders>OrderID}"/>
                <m:Text text="{ path : 'Orders>OrderDate', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style : 'long' } }"/>
                <m:Text text="{ path : 'Orders>RequiredDate', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style : 'long' } }"/>
                <m:Text text="{Orders>ShipPostalCode}"/>
                <m:Text text="{Orders>ShipCity}"/>
                <m:Text text="{Orders>ShipCountry}"/>
            </m:cells>
        </m:ColumnListItem>
    </m:items>
</m:Table>
```

I would like to hide the column `Order date`, when the screen resize is `Phone`. As you can see, the setting for the column `Order date` is:

```
<m:Column minScreenWidth="Medium" demandPopin="true">
    <m:Text text="Order date"/>
</m:Column>
```

The column `Order date` should be hide on the `Phone`. How to archive it?

Comment: Please, check the [API reference of `setMinScreenWidth`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Column/methods/setMinScreenWidth)

Comment: Also, be aware **not** to apply `demandPopin` on every Column. See https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1396

Comment: Check best way/recommendation while working with responsive table https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsive-table/#responsiveness-and-adaptiveness

Comment: I would set minScreenWidth property to "Tablet" instead of "Medium"

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making a Device model in your Component `init` method. You could do it like this:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(sap.ui.Device);
this.setModel(oModel, "device");
```

Then, you could bind the `visible` property to resolve to `true` when the device is not a phone like:

```
<m:Column visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}" minScreenWidth="Medium" demandPopin="true">
    <m:Text text="Order date"/>
</m:Column>
```

If that doesn't work, the Device model has some other properties you can play with, like `device>/resize/width` or you can even attach a handler to the [resize](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.Device.resize/methods/Summary) API that fires on screen resizing (if you want it to trigger on resizing rather than only by device) by calling in your `onInit` method:

```
sap.ui.Device.resize.attachHandler(function(mParams){ 
    // do what you want with mParams.height or mParams.width
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the device type in the controller and try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427141/sapui5-hiding-a-table-column) or you can set a **sapUiVisibleOnlyOnDesktop** class to column as it is shown [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/d6/3a15e5eebb45cdada317bae5f45bc2/content.htm?no_cache=true).

Comment: Just to note, this class doesn't work for every control, e.g. the class isn't getting applied when added to a SegmentedButtonItem within the items aggregation of a SegmentedButton. Had to use the solution with: visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}"